# What are the recognized languages that can be passed to clang with the `-x` flag?

Tags: clang

The [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-x-language) doesn't list acceptable values:

> -x, --language , --language=¶
>
> Treat subsequent input files as having type

Answer (score 1):

It seems the best way is to look at the source, currently in [`include/clang/Driver/Types.def`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/release_60/include/clang/Driver/Types.def).

The first column is the string you'd use as an argument. Lines with a 'u' in the list column string can be specified as arguments to the `-x` command line flag.

Here's an excerpt:

```
TYPE("ir",                       LLVM_IR,      INVALID,         "ll",    "u")
TYPE("ir",                       LLVM_BC,      INVALID,         "bc",    "u")
TYPE("lto-ir",                   LTO_IR,       INVALID,         "s",     "")
TYPE("lto-bc",                   LTO_BC,       INVALID,         "o",     "")
```